# Catching errors from server side

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, mysql-error-1146

I am getting json data from my server to show them as a table.

```
$('#queryFrom').ajaxForm({                    
                dataType:  'json',                                        
                beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
                success:   processJson,                    
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    $('#queryResult').html('<div class="ui-corner-all ui-state-error"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>'+thrownError+'</p></div>');
                    $('#queryResult').show("slow");
                }
            });
```

Can I somehow separate the mysql errors from json/ajax erros side?
Currently I am getting :**Invalid JSON: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'simover.simulation' doesn't exist{}**
Can I customise the messages thrown by jquery?
thanks Arman.

**EDIT**

one can use **xhr.responceTxt** instead of **thrownError**.

Comment: You should catch and process the MySQL errors on the server side and return e.g. an empty result set. Server error messages should never get to the client.

Comment: Have you turned off the `display_errors` option in `php.ini`?

Comment: I would like to see the errors. The user interface provides facility to submit queries to server. If I return empty set again the Invalid JSON: stays there. I want to have a custom message, like: Sorry your query is wrong and point what is wrong.

Comment: Is this a public application? If you display these kind of errors, they could reveal information about your database that might help someone break into it. You may wish to have an option in your application to disable these errors altogether, or only display them if the client has a particular IP address

Comment: @Ken The expert users are going to access, for the guests it is prepared statements, in that case we don't have any errors at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your error callback is getting called because you have an error in your server response, not because your server encountered a problem. Javascript engine throws an error because it expects JSON data to be sent back, but instead it gets a plain string `Base table or view not found...`, which is not a valid JSON string.

I would suggest that you catch those errors on the server for example by using `try` and `catch` blocks and sending back some kind of special response in case an error occurs. Like this:

```
{
    "ok": false, 
    "error_key": "database_error", 
    "error_text": "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'simover.simulation' doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thanks!
I found also that my all thrown errors from databaseclass I can read from: xhr.responseText